# Linq2Sql SubmitChanges Fails for Remote DB !

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
var user = dataContext.Users.Single(where u.Name == "SomeName");
user.SomeProperty = SomeValue;
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

I am using VS 2008 \ Linq2Sql to connect to a **remote database** and am trying to update a property of the user record. But SubmitChanges method fails with an exception *"Row not found or changed"*. However, the most weird thing is that the code above works *if the database is local* to the machine.

The user table has a primary key as suggested in a few other posts that discuss the problem of this kind.

Your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please try enabling distributed transaction Coordinator service.